# Is Mohammed a deity?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

Recently, someone reportedly described Mohammed as a deity. Oddly enough, it wasn't someone insulting him that described him as a deity, but someone responding to him saying that you can't insult a deity. Is Mohammed regarded as a deity by Muslims?

I think I know the answer to this, but a quick google search can't confirm it.

Comment: I have never came across anyone who claims Muhammad pbuh as a diety. He is the Messenger \prophet of Allah.

Comment: I acknowledge the fact that this question is very old but still curious to ask, may I know what language and what exact word did that person say to refer to Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) as a deity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No Prophet Mohamed was not a deity nor do we believe he was divine.  He was a human being.

Allah is the only deity we believe in and worship.

Answer (score 12):

> **Say," I am just a human being like you. It has been revealed to me that your God is the One God. So whoever expects to encounter his Lord
>   let him act righteously, and not associate anyone with the worship of
>   his Lord."** (18:110)

This is the last verse of Surah Cave which is clearly stating that Prophet Muhammad is just a human being like anyone else, living, eating, working, sleeping etc., except for the fact that Towhid (monotheism) was revealed to him.

In this verse Allah is rejecting the wrong concept: that Prophets are deities because they are aware of Unseen world through revelation.

Answer (score 4):

The Prophet Mohammad (pbuh) was the messenger of Allah. Following verse confirms it

> قُلْ إِنَّمَا أَنَا بَشَرٌ مِّثْلُكُمْ يُوحَى إِلَيَّ أَنَّمَا
>   إِلَهُكُمْ إِلَهٌ وَاحِدٌ  فَمَن كَانَ يَرْجُو لِقَاء رَبِّهِ
>   فَلْيَعْمَلْ عَمَلًا صَالِحًا وَلَا يُشْرِكْ بِعِبَادَةِ رَبِّهِ
>   أَحَدًا
>
> say: I am but a man like yourselves, (but) the inspiration has come to me, that your Allah is one Allah: whoever expects to meet his
>   Lord, let him work righteousness, and, in the worship of his lord,
>   admit no one as partner. (Surah of the cave, verse110)

The Prophet leaded or preached all men to worship only Allah as god of creatures and all instruments of Islam are based on the oneness of Allah.